# Snap.js Side Panel Default To Open?

Tags: jquery

I am using Snap.js (https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js/) to build a new framework for a site and I am wondering if anyone knows a way to have the sidebar default to open vs. closed when you come to the page. I want to force the user to have to toggle close in order to hide the sidebar (snap-drawer-left). I

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution: I added:

```
style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(266px, 0px, 0px);"
```

to my snap-content element.

Answer (score 0):

Another (not clean) solution is to click on your "toggle" button automatically, when the page is initially loaded:

```
$timeout(function() {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#myToggle')).triggerHandler('click');
}, 0);
```