# angular-snap close drawer after click on link

Tags: angularjs, snap.js

i have this html structure and i use angular-snap module:

```
<div snap-drawer id="menu">
     <a href="#profile">profile</a>
     <hr/>
     <a href="#cart">cart</a>
</div>

<div snap-content>
     <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

When I click on one of the links in the snap-drawer, snap-content correctly loads the page but the snap-drawer will not close.

How can I close it? if you use the directive 'snap-close' on the link, the snap-drawer closes but the snap content does not load page.

Thanks

Comment: Please see the plunker it will help you `visit the link`http://plnkr.co/edit/usbx8yP1fXMJleR3iqZ8?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[Snap.js Side Panel Default To Open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246487/snap-js-side-panel-default-to-open) helped me with the same problem; try

```
<div snap-content style="-webkit-transformk: translate3d(266px, 0px, 0px);">
     <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

I think this works because default snap maxPosition is 266.